# Remove OK button from dialog

Tags: java, gxt

I've created a Dialog using GXT, but I don't know how to remove the OK button.

My code for creating the dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
dialog.setHeadingText("My group invites");
dialog.setPixelSize(100, 100);
dialog.setHideOnButtonClick(true);
dialog.addButton(new TextButton("TEST", new SelectHandler(){

    @Override
    public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}));
```

Result: [image]

Anybody knows how to get rid of the OK button?

I'm using Sencha GXT 3.1.0 beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `setPredefinedButtons` Method from Dialog class.

Comment: I've tried setPredefinedButtons(null) earlier with a crash as the result. But calling setPredefinedButtons() without any arguments it removes the button. Thank you Jens!

Answer (score 0):

Before adding any button just do:

```
dialog.getButtonBar().clear();
```

That should work.